# How can I start searching for matches in my Recycler View after intenting string for search to my EditText

Tags: java, android, search, android-intent

I have my `RecyclerView` with `EditText` for searching matches filled with data from Firebase Database. When I'm typing some word in `EditText` by myself, all works fine, but if i try to `intent` word for search from another activity to this `EditText`, nothing works. To make search work after that, I need to change some letter in intented word.

This is my code in OnCreate:

```
if(getIntent().getExtras() != null) {

   Intent intent = getIntent();
    String str = intent.getStringExtra("trickname");
    editSearch.setText(str);

}


editSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        search(s.toString());
    }
});
```

And search method:

```
private void search(String str){
    ArrayList<Trick> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Trick object : list){
        if((object.getDescription().toLowerCase().contains(str.toLowerCase().trim())) || (object.getName().toLowerCase().contains(str.toLowerCase().trim()))){
            myList.add(object);
        }
    }
    AdapterClass adapterClass = new AdapterClass(myList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterClass);
}
```

Intent from another activity:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(ProgressActivity.this, EncyActivity.class);
intent1.putExtra("trickname", button1.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent1);
```

Word in `EditText` is intented, but search is not working. If i'm typing this word by myself, search is working and finding matches

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just call `search(str);` after `editSearch.setText(str);`

Comment: I've tried now, but it leads to ```java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.ArrayList.iterator()' on a null object reference```

Comment: That means that you list is empty, do the search at the end after everything is initialised

Comment: Oh, yes, it helped. Thank you!